# Dagger inject Context in a ModelView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger, model-view

I'm trying to inject the `Context` in my ModelView but I'm a little bit confused:

Here is my `Module`, I send him an `Application` for later use the context from this, but I don't know where it comes from this `Application` or how to take it:

```
@Module
class module {
    @Provides @Singleton fun appContext(application: Application): Context{
        return application
    }
}
```

And here is my `Component`:

```
@Component(modules = [module::class])
interface component {
    fun providesApplication(): Application
}
```

To finish I don't know how to inject this in my ViewModel because this don't have constructor to inject it.

How should I inject the context to my `ViewModel`?

Comment: why do you want to inject context to the ViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already build-in `ViewModel` with context, replace inheritance from `ViewModel` with `AndroidViewModel`

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel

Comment: And how I should replace this line: viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java) because it jumps me an alert.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you could try something like this :

```
class YourViewModel @Inject constructor(context:Context) : ViewModel()
```

**Merely a suggestion if nothing else works, hear me out...**

```
var context: Context? = null

fun initViewModelWithContext(context: Context) {
    this.context = context
}
```

you could potentially do something like this as well, if you don't find a solution with dagger. all your functions can then use this local instance of context, and this `ViewModel` will be destroyed/created as it is needed so it won't be causing any memory issues

Comment: Interesting... but then I should inject the a constructor instead of a Context? I don't know how to finish it.

Comment: The context is required, because I have a few fun who need it. However, I try what you say but the thing Is I need to make the builder and it usually done in the constructor.

Comment: I think what you are trying to made is inject a full constructor to my ViewModel right?